# React installation issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image: This is an image of installing react on my pc]

> it is getting stuck after showing found 1 low security vulnerability and not creating src and public folder due to that i am not able to run the command **npm start** .

Errors:

$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-14T15_05_28_068Z-debug.log

Comment: what do you mean you cant ?? is it for any error or just for that vunerability ??
If its for any err, whats that ??

Comment: I don't see an error. You should probably add more details to the question about your project setup and what you have tried. Images of code is a bad idea if the image is removed in future. The info for future users will be lost.

Comment: Please add errors you are getting after `npm start`. I believe even after vulnerabilities, you can at least start the project. If an error occurs, post the errors in question

Comment: I have edited my question can you please tell me now what to do with that error.

Comment: I think you need to be in the directory `my-app` to run NPM.